# Redirect .htaccess through partial modification of the link in its middle

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

please show me the right way. I`m trying to redirect

from

```
example.com/home/<anything>
```

to

```
example.com/home-3/<anything>
```

It still goes very difficult to me with RegExp, moreover in `.htaccess` conditionals.

Please show me the correct way to do this

My basic thoughts didn't play well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/home-3/ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*)/home/(.*) $1/home-3/$2
 </IfModule>
```

it does nothing with:

```
https://example.com/home/information/work
```

but must become

```
https://example.com/home-3/information/work
```

However php-redirect would be done properly with:
(`header.php`)

```
IF ( ($do_redirect=true) == true) {{{
            $address=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            $addrstart = substr($address,0,15);
            $sch = strpos($addrstart,'home/');


            if ($sch!== false) {
                $ndl = 'home/';
                $nw = 'home-3/';
                    $rezz = str_replace($ndl,$nw,$address);
                    $address = $rezz;

                    header("Location: https://egf.ru/".$urrr);
                    die;
            } 

}}}
```

So I'm trying to do the same through `.htaccess` instead of  header location.

Added:
[image: ftp]
[image: ht1]
[image: ht2]
[image: ht_tries_out]
I tried every of this combination through private tab with closing a singlelast private window and reopening every time.

I also tried to check one of Redirect at  ht2 image - it also gave me 404/

I think 
OR htaccess somehow really doesnt work with wordpress (0_o)
OR Ihave lost something fundamental/

So being reinspired to recheck one time more 
Ive done next:
Uncommented all of the variants:
[image: totAL war]

and it does also nothing (404) at home/.. addressing
all home-3 are working fine

update 
in 7 minutes server fall down
ftp no response, site egf.ru no response.
last htacces modification is next:
[image: last one htaccess modification]
looks like no cyclic recursion 
all htaccess checkers says no errors.

Don`t know is it providers fault or mine.

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? In the document root? Or in this `/home` or `/home-3` directory?

Comment: the wordpress has no both of them. Neither home, nor home-3 - they both dont exists in real.

htaccess is based in main root directory of site. Ill try to add images into the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Readed lots of manuals to understand the topic 
and to write a proper commands.

Please Excuse me for the such a silly question. It was really time-taking to figure out)

But Full and Final Conclusion was achieved through  the [.htaccess debugger](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) =))

So Final working code =>

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home-3 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ 
RewriteRule "^home(.*)" "home-3$1" [L]
```

[image]

Comment: This an _internal rewrite_ (URL does not change), not an external "redirect", as stated in your question? Your PHP code also performs an external "redirect" (not and internal rewrite). (?)

Comment: you are right, php doing external redirect (because I dont know if php could do inner one:))
for that purpose I hoped .htaccess would be succeeded in any of them.

but I still cant get nothing successful with  htaccess =(

Comment: Moreover - nothing seems to works 

neither RewriteRule (.*) /anypage [R=301,L] nor  RewriteRule (.*) /anypage [L]

And I cannot find a way to debug it in apache =(

Comment: Redirect 302 /home/ /home-3/ doesn`t work also. It looks like no any rule that was previously or is now in the htaccess (located at basic directory) - nothing works =( How can it be. How can I get debuging data?

Comment: Neither of those `RewriteRule` directives will work as they will create a redirect loop and a rewrite loop (500 error) respectively. You should not use `Redirect` with WordPress, because of potential conflicts with existing directives. Do you have access to the server config? You can enable mod_rewrite debugging in the server config (not `.htaccess`) and examine the server's error log for debug info. But when you saying "nothing works" - what exactly happens? An error? Nothing at all?

Comment: @MrWhite

Server falls. Dont know why.
last changes - htaccess to openevrything to check if would at least any of them work.. Changed htaccess and then checked - nothing was redirected or rewrited.

But in 5 minutes server falls. ftp no response. egf.ru no response.could it be the reason and how to heal?(

htaccess looks like has no fullcyclic recursions...

# BEGIN WordPress

Answer (score 0):

To "redirect" from `/home/<anything>` to `/home-3/<anything>` you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/(.*) /home-3/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Although you don't necessarily need mod_rewrite for this, as a simple mod_alias `Redirect` (which is prefix-matching) would suffice:

```
Redirect 302 /home/ /home-3/
```

`/home/<anything>` is implicitly redirected to `/home-3/<anything>` because of the prefix-matching nature of the `Redirect` directive. Everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL.

However, I suspect you have other mod_rewrite rewrites already (in order to route the URL), so you may need the mod_rewrite solution above in order to avoid conflicts.

---

Looking at your directives...

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>  RewriteEngine On
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/home-3/ [NC]
>  RewriteRule (.*)/home/(.*) $1/home-3/$2
>  </IfModule>
> ```

This wouldn't have matched `/home/information/work` because of the first slash prefix in the regex `(.*)/....`. But your example URLs show `/home/` at the *start* of the URL-path, so there is nothing to match before it. So, `^home/(.*)` would suffice. The `^` is a start-of-string *anchor* , so the pattern must occur at the start of the URL-path.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home-3 [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ 
> RewriteRule "^home(.*)" "home-3$1" [L]
> ```

The "working" code in your deleted answer, had this more complex rule. However, this matches `/home<anything>`, not `/home/<anything>` (as stated in your question) - which does complicate matters. The 1st condition (`RewriteCond` directive) is then required to prevent a rewrite loop<sup>***1**</sup>. The 2nd condition is not required here, since the condition must be true if the `RewriteRule` had already matched.

<sup>***1**</sup> Note that this rule is an *internal rewrite* (URL does not visibly change to the user), not an external "redirect" as stated in your question. Note that your PHP code that you stated works OK, is an external "redirect", not a rewrite.

Comment: Thank you very much. You know, the worst thing I faced (and that was the reason for deleting everything)- 

that all the variants of code I wrote and some of them was working - now - do not work at all - noone of them =(((((

It seems like I had lost something very important and small and unknown to me =(

Comment: I understood on the matter of Outter redirect and inner redirect(rewrite).

I think to heal seo I should do inner redirect from /home/ to /home-3/
because the wordpress site suddenly become broken and changed all links from home/ to home-3/  . I cannot heal it. So i decided to do hidden inner redirect for the Google WEbmaster and Yandexe Webmaster would think that everything is ok and we would not loast our positions(

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache (if you've previously experimented with 301 - permanent - redirects then these will have been cached by the browser). These directives should also be at the top of your `.htaccess` file _before_ existing rewrites. For SEO you should be using a "redirect", not a "rewrite", otherwise you are potentially creating _duplicate content_. (What is the reason for this redirect/rewrite in the first place? Has the content moved?).

Comment: "WordPress" - Ah, that is the problem with _rewrites_ - you can't internally rewrite the URL if you are using WordPress, because of the way WordPress routes URLs. If you rewrite the URL in `.htaccess` then WP still sees the original URL as requested, not the rewritten URL, so would likely result in a 404. (You would need to do this entirely within WP if you specifically need a "rewrite" - although WP does it its own way - it's not technically an Apache URL-rewrite.) You can still use a "redirect" in `.htaccess` though - that should still work.

Comment: Thank You Great for caring) It sheds a light on fog of my ignorance!))

The reason was - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022815/wordpress-suddenly-changed-url-addressing-style-from-abc-net-home-to-abc-ne